# Does Z3 support EPR logic with stratified function symbols?

Tags: z3

There is an extension of the EPR fragment of first-order logic with functions symbols, as long as the sorts of the functions are structured in the right way. This is studied in this paper [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717109001102), and also cited in the PhD thesis by Voigt [here](https://publikationen.sulb.uni-saarland.de/handle/20.500.11880/27767). In the latter this is stated as follows:

**Proposition 3.14.4** ([ARS10, GdM09, Kor13b]). *The satisﬁability problem for multi-sorted ∃ * ∀ *  sentences over a stratiﬁed vocabulary is decidable.*

where a "stratified vocabulary" can contain function symbols but, indeed, with sorts structured accordingly.

If I'm not wrong, Z3 has ad-hoc procedures for the EPR fragment. Does it, by chance, support this extended fragment as well?

Comment: This question is better suited for https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions. If you do get an answer there, please post your findings here for there record.

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks!